# Find the points which do not lie on the image of a parameterisation

Tags: differential-geometry, span, parametrization

I've been struggling on this question for quite some time now and I cannot seem to find anything online to assist.

I've been given the parametrisation:

$p(u,v)=\left (\cos u \cos v, \frac{1}{3}\sin u \cos v, \ \frac{1}{2}\sin v  \right )$,

$\pi <u< \pi$,

$-\frac{\pi}{2}<v<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The question asks to find the set of points $(x,y,z)$ satisfying  $x^2+9y^2+4z^2=1$ which **do not** lie on the image of $p(u,v)$.

I know this is a straightforward question but I'm not the brightest of individuals and I'm struggling to work it out. I suspect it has something to do with $u,v$ belonging to open intervals. Is there an easy/methodical way to approach this question?

the answer is:
$\left \{(x,y,z):x^2+9y^2+4z^2=1, x \leq 0, y=0  \right \}$

I am sorry to ask such a trivial question but it's been puzzling me for a while now and I'm not making any progress. Many Thanks :)

Comment: You may think you're not "the brightest" but your solid grammar would indicate otherwise.

Comment: @GregoryGrant It certainly is a breath of fresh air to stimble upon such good grammar.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss It's rare enough that one can't help but notice when somebody writes well.

Comment: When I first went for permission to be a math major, some 32 years ago, the professor didn't ask me if I did well in my math classes.  Instead he wanted to make sure I was doing well in English.  He told me that's just as important if you're going to major in math.  So true.

Comment: You say $\pi<u<\pi$.  I assume you mean $-\pi<u<\pi$?

Comment: If $y=0$ then $u=0$ (because $\cos v\not=0$ $\forall$ $v\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$) which means $x=\cos v$, but $\cos v>0$ for $-\pi/2<v<\pi/2$.  So it's clear that if $y=0$ and $x\leq0$ it's not in the image.  The converse is not so obvious.

Comment: You are both very kind. Thank you for spotting the typo. It should read  $-\pi < u < \pi$.

Comment: It's also clear that the image is in that surface right? But I'm stuck on showing all those points are actually there in the image, sorry I can't help better, but it is 2am here...

Comment: Yes, I have been given that the image is in that surface - sorry for not mentioning it. Thankfully, your post has given me some inspiration. It's not quite water tight but it does provide a starting point for coming up with the solution. 

$\left (\cos u \cos v, \frac{1}{3} \sin u \cos v, \frac{1}{2} \sin v   \right ) = \cos v\left ( \cos u, \frac{1}{3}\sin u, \frac{1}{2}\tan v  \right )$. As you pointed out, $\sin u =0 \iff u=0$. Setting $u=0$ we obtain, $\cos v\left ( 1, 0, \frac{1}{2}\tan v  \right )$. Now, $\cos v >0$. Thus, only positive values in the first component can be generated.

Comment: I still feel that the above isn't the best way of approaching the question. It certainly doesn't, to me at least, provide a justification as to why $\left \{(x,y,z):x^2+9y^2+4z^2=1, x \leq 0, y=0  \right \}$ is the only set of points which doesn't lie in the image of the parametrisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Geometrically, if $u$ and $v$ are real, then
$$
(x, y, z) = (\cos u \cos v, \sin u \cos v, \sin v)
$$
is the point on the unit sphere $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1$ with longitude $u$ and latitude $v$ (in radians). The restrictions $-\pi < u < \pi$ and $-\pi/2 < v < \pi/2$ omit the open half-circle where longitude is $\pi$, and the two poles. To handle your question, scale this picture by $\frac{1}{3}$ in the $y$-direction and by $\frac{1}{2}$ in the $z$-direction.

If you need to be more rigorous than this, I'd suggest letting $U$ denote the sphere with the closed half-circle $u = \pi$ (including the poles) removed, defining $q:U \to (-\pi, \pi) \times (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ by
$$
q(x, y, z) = (\operatorname{atan2}(y, x), \arcsin z),
$$
(with $\operatorname{atan2}$ the polar angle function defined on the plane with the non-positive $x$-axis removed and taking values in $(-\pi, \pi)$), and showing/observing that $q$ is a two-sided functional inverse of $p$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the response. It has taken me some time, but I'm now at a stage where I understand what's going on.